# How to create List-like UserControl in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I want to create my own expandable/collapsable tree-like UserControl, which nodes are the Border elements with any content. And this control should have the *single* SelectedItem. When I select one of the nodes I want to see details information about selected item.

I've done the control's presentation and a piece of logic:
I can see all the tree of elements, collaps any node(s), select one of them and see details. But I can't do bidirectional binding. I.e. I want to have an opportunity to change fields in details panel and immidiately see changes in the tree-control.

Help me please either call force update (rebind data) of the control (just give a tip how to perform this) or give an advise how to create my own List-like UserControl.
I tried to make my control inherit from some ListBox class but I couldn't.

PS. Sorry for my bad English...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `TreeView` control.

Comment: Can I customize it to be, for example, like this (of course, without connection lines): http://techbase.kde.org/File:QtDOM_TreeStructure.png